# Backup a database with CRON on Raspberry

Tags: mysql, database, cron, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to backup a database on my Raspberry via a CRON task every day at midnight but it doesn't work at all.

I edit the file /etc/crontab to add my task :

59 23 * * * root /home/pi/backupdb.sh

And my backupdb.sh is :

mysqldump --user USER --password=PASS areadb > backupdb.txt

If anyone can give some help ? The mysqldump request works in the shell so maybe the problem come from the cron task?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution. I have to give to my .sh file the permission to be executable.

Just add :
chmod +x /home/pi/backupdb.sh

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with Raspberry, but here are some debugging steps you can follow.

1. Add logs to your shell file and check which command fails.
2. Execute the shell file at now instead of midnight to see what went wrong.
3. Also make sure that the path you are using to point to your shell file exists and is accessible.
4. A link to understand crons better https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/cron.md

Comment: I already follow your link to develop my backup. I change the hour of execution everytime i made a change and the path is also the right one. I'm gonna change it to see if it's coming from there